# Notification in python without stopping the script

Tags: python, notifications

I was writing code using python and opencv. If no face is detected it should notify the windows10 user. I used win10toast

```
import time
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

notif = ToastNotifier()

notif.show_toast(title= "Nusrat", msg= "One baby is missing")
time.sleep(10)
```

but it stops the code when notification is being shown. Is there any way I can show notification using gui or anything but that will not stop the code?

Comment: async/non-blocking I/O is what you're looking for I believe

Comment: @agg3l this isn't an IO question, this is about displaying something to the UI

Comment: Have you checked [the library's site](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications)? The example in the landing page shows you can use `threaded=True`

Answer (score 2):

The [library's Github repo](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications) shows how to avoid blocking in the landing page example :

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
import time

toaster = ToastNotifier()

toaster.show_toast("Example two",
               "This notification is in it's own thread!",
               icon_path=None,
               duration=5,
               threaded=True)
# Wait for threaded notification to finish
while toaster.notification_active(): time.sleep(0.1)
```

You need to add the `threaded=True` parameter. Sleeping is only needed if you want to check whether the notification is still active.

Displaying notification is *not* a blocking operation. The [library's code](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/blob/master/win10toast/__init__.py#L111) forces a sleep equal to `duration` before closing the window :

```
# take a rest then destroy
sleep(duration)
DestroyWindow(self.hwnd)
UnregisterClass(self.wc.lpszClassName, None)
```

`threaded=True` will execute the `show/sleep/destroy` flow in a separate thread. Frankly, there are cleaner ways to do that, eg using a one-off timer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. When I first used the win10toast it worked with all the delay and everything. It just paused my actual code which job was to continuously read camera. 
Now I tried your code but I don't know what happened it just blinks and nothing shows. I ran the code from powershell and also from vsCode's prompt. a python icon blinks on one corner of my task bar and nothing.

Comment: It's the libary's sample, not mine. It does work. Did you try it exactly as it is? It contains a 5 second delay, did you use that?

Comment: I used that, but still the problem remains.

Comment: @AshrafMinhaj used what? Post the *exact* code. This code runs just fine, displays the notification fro 5 seconds, then polls it until it closes

Comment: I'm sorry for late, I actually ran the same code as you have posted.